# How to create a H2OFrame using H2O REST API

Tags: rest, h2o

Is it possible to create a H2OFrame using the H2O's REST API and if so how?

My main objective is to utilize models stored inside H2O so as to make predictions on **external** H2OFrames.

I need to be able to generate those H2OFrames externally from JSON (I suppose by calling an endpoint)

I read the API documentation but couldn't find any clear explanation.

I believe that the closest endpoints are

[/3/CreateFrame](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/rest-api-reference.html#route-%2F3%2FCreateFrame) which creates random data and [/3/ParseSetup](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/rest-api-reference.html#route-%2F3%2FParseSetup)

but I couldn't find any reliable tutorial.

Comment: Can you explain more about the data you want in a frame. Is it going to be random data? Or is it real data, you currently have in some file format (or in an SQL DB)?

Comment: @Darren_Cook I want to create a tiny data frame by passing a json with the same number and property names required by the h2o model, in order to predict something based in such features.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no REST API endpoint to directly convert some JSON record into a `Frame` object. Thus, the only way forward for you would be to first write the data to a CSV file, then upload it to h2o using `POST /3/PostFile`, and then parse using `POST /3/Parse`.

(Note that `POST /3/PostFile` endpoint is not in the documentation. This is because it is [handled separately](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-core/src/main/java/water/JettyHTTPD.java#L311) from the other endpoints. Basically, it's an endpoint that takes an arbitrary file in the body of the post request, and saves it as "raw data file").

The same job is much easier to do in Python or in R: for example in order to upload some dataset into h2o for scoring, you only need to say

```python
df = h2o.H2OFrame(plaindata)
```

Comment: Re: "PostFile is not in documentation". Is it just "not documented yet", or is it not officially part of the public interface (e.g. so it might change in future).

Comment: @DarrenCook It *is* part of the public interface, so it's not going to change in the future. It is not in the official documentation yet because it doesn't follow the standard scheme of all other endpoints, so it may require some hacking to it properly documented.

Answer (score 0):

I am already doing something similar in my project. Since, there is no REST API endpoint to directly convert JSON record into a Frame object. So, I am doing the following: -

1- For Model Building:- first transfer and write the data into the CSV file where h2o server or cluster is running.Then import data into the h2o using POST /3/ImportFiles, and then parse and build a model etc. I am using the h2o-bindings APIs (RESTful APIs) for it. Since I have a large data (hundreds MBs to few GBs), so I use /3/ImportFiles instead POST /3/PostFile as latter is slow to upload large data.

2- For Model Scoring or Prediction:- I am using the Model MOJO and POJO. In your case, you use POST /3/PostFile as suggested by @Pasha, if your data is not large. But, as per h2o documentation, it's advisable to use the MOJO or POJO for model scoring or prediction in a production environment and not to call h2o server/cluster directly. MOJO and POJO are thread safe, so you can scale it using multithreading for concurrent requests.

Comment: Hey, I am using h2o-bindings api to train model. I used "h2o.train_gbm(gbmParams);" and got "ModelKeyV3 modelKey = (ModelKeyV3)job.dest;
ModelsV3 models = h2o.model(modelKey); GBMModelV3 model = (GBMModelV3)models.models[0];"  . But I don't know how to transform the GBMModelV3 to MOJO model. I didn't find any method that can do this kind of things. So how can I got mojo model in h2o-bindings api? ps： I am using java.