# How can I get elasticsearch data in h2o?

Tags: elasticsearch, h2o

I have data loaded in elasticsearch. 
How can I get elasticsearch data in h2o?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way or API available to load data into H2O from elasticsearch. h2o supports files and JDBC, so you can write the data into the CSV file from ES. Then import data into the h2o using POST /3/ImportFiles. You can refer my answer related to it at [how to create an h2oframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184473/how-to-create-a-h2oframe-using-h2o-rest-api/48465047#48465047)

Answer (score 0):

Going to be dead blunt on this. One is asking about an ETL process. Basically, all one does is export your index as a csv into say a hadoop, a cloud bucket, or SQL database then follow one of the various tutorials to import the dataset into h2o.

Personally, I'd just use an Airflow DAG to export from ELK, convert it into a pandas dataframe, then upload the dataframe to a PostgreSQL database; then follow that up with a h2o wave script that's triggered as Airflow DAG off the new data in the database.

One could just do this all with a bunch of bash scripts and cron jobs too.

Answer (score -1):

The latest version of elasticsearch comes with an sql interface that can be connected to via jdbc or odbc. I haven't attempted to use this with H2O but in theory...